# iptables - allow connections only from LAN

Tags: ssh, iptables, local-area-network, wide-area-network

Is there a way to deny all `external traffic (WAN)` to `SSH` and allow only local traffic `(192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255)` and what would be the rule?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer then accept it.

Answer (score 3):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --source 192.168.0.1/24 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have a rule up the INPUT chain that accepts ESTABLISHED traffic already. That would be crucial. Just FYI for anyone else attempting to use this answer.

Comment: @Nimmy Lebby: That may be a questionable assumption, considering the answer also includes a `--source` with a malformed network range. I believe `iptables` will interpret it as `192.168.0.0/24`, which, fortunately, seems to be the desired range. IMO, this question and answer seem to have garnered more than a few egg-nog inspired upvotes.

Comment: I was going to comment on the network address as well but I have tested it and, yes, your belief on the iptables interpretation is correct. And I wish I had some eggnog myself.